# How to include a function call in a Django template?

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have a function in my Django app (1.7) and I want to include the results from this function in a template. My function is in a utils.py file that is in the same folder with models.py, views.py, and urls.py.

The code for my function in utils.py is:

```
class Defin():
    global infotree_graph
    graph = neo4j.GraphDatabaseService("http://<your_url>:7474/db/data/")

    def fetch_overview(self):
        overview_query = "<query>"  
        results = neo4j.CypherQuery(graph, bacm_overview_query).execute()        

        for r in results:        
            definition = r['definition']

        return definition
```

When I run this function on its own in python, I get the correct string.

Here is my view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from myapp import utils

def introduction(request):
    return render(request, 'myapp/introduction.html')

def bacm(request):
    return render(request, 'myapp/definition.html')
```

And in my template I am including:

```
{{ utils.Defin.fetch_overview }}
```

And I get nothing on the screen. Is this a reasonable approach? Is there a better way to include the results from a function in a template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have something like this at the end of your view:

```
return render(response, self.template_name, context)
```

Make sure you include the result of your function in the context:

```
context={
    'fetch_result': foo.fetch_result(),
}
```

And finally in your template call it like:

```
{{ fetch_result }}
```

Templates only know about your context

Comment: So where do I put the context statement inside the function in the view? I'll add my view to my question. Thanks for your specific answer.

Comment: Yeah, you context is defined in your view and then passed to render as a third argument.

Answer (score 2):

For a start, there seems to be no good reason for that code to be in a class. Python is not Java; put the function at module level. Quite apart from anything else, you can't call an instance method via the class itself; you'd have to have an instance of Defin.

Secondly, you could only call this from the template if you'd passed the name `utils` into the template context; you don't show your view, but it seems unlikely you'd have done that.

Finally, you should ask why you want to be calling it from the template at all. Much better to call it in the view, and pass the result into the template.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Yes, I don't need the class. I was using more as a method of organization since I will have dozens of these database retrieval functions. You are right that I did not include utils in the template context. Since I have so many of these database calls to add I want to make sure I do it the right way so I can expand it with the app. So I appreciate your suggestions on the right pattern.